# How to make database uptodate without any user request?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I am trying to develop an application which will download some json strings(greetings) from server .As I am new to android,I don't know exactly how to do that.The application will have its own inbox which will be implemented through sqlite and system will download all the latest greetings(json strings) automatically from server and will put them in the inbox.So what is best approach for this,I mean should I use SERVICES or Async Tasks  for it ???I want that whenever a new greeting comes to the server, my application should download it automatically without any user request and when user opens the inbox,it is uptodate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are more appropriate to the use case that you have described here. services are meant to be used in the scenarios when you are not sure when the data will be arriving and you want to keep checking for it in the background without letting the user know that something is going on Asynctask on the other hand is more useful when u need to do some network dependent thing or something that will take time after a user clicks on something.The asynctask is just another way to show the user a proper waiting progress bar or something while the application is processing the user's request so that the user doesnt feel like the app is stuck. So SERVICES it is for your case.

Comment: Yes Waseem thats the best practice and its not about performance as much its about preventing the service from blocking on an IO in case the net connectivity is slow or any other reason. Read this thread http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/49c7af6c5d4a3b6d?pli=1

Comment: welcome and if this has helped you with your problem can you plz accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update the database even if the app is not running you will need a service or a sync account

for services 
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

for the sync adapter 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

I implemented something similar using a  service